# Do Chilean 72 hour transit visas give you a full 72 hours in the country, or three days?

Tags: visas, transit, overstaying

My question is specifically about Chilean transit visas which are described as "up to 72 hours".

Can someone clarify whether I get to stay in the country for 72 hours, measured from when immigration gives me an entry stamp until when they give me exit stamp.

I am worried that it might mean up to three days calendar stay, as the entry stamp only indicates the day of entry.

[image: from wikimedia commons]
**Source**: https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Chile_Entrada_Stamp.jpg

Comment: If it's **up to** 72 hours, I presume it's three calendar days, but a quick trawl did not find official sources either way.

Answer (score 5):

> My question is specifically about Chilean transit visas which are described as "up to 72 hours".
> ... as the entry stamp only indicates the day of entry.

As written: **up to 72 hours**.

If you arrive at 2019-02-19 06:00, you would have **66 hours** (**up to** 72 hours).

But it looks as if Chile does not issue transit visas **and** that you must leave on the same day (possibly without being given a stamp).

---

> [ABOUT TRANSIT PASSENGERS - Chile en el Exterior](https://www.chile.gob.cl/wellington/about-transit-passengers)
>
> **Chile does not have transit visas**. You can remain at the international lounge for as long as you wait for the next flight (transit time is **up to 24 hours**).
> Chile provides Tourist visas, and tourist visas are given to those who want to leave the airport and stay in the city.
>
> It is important to mention that any citizen in transit that stays at the international lounge of the airport waiting for their next flight does not need to apply for a visa.
>
> If the passenger wishes to leave the airport, then he needs to apply for a tourist visa, and in that case, all applications must be submitted to the General Consulate of Chile in Wellington, process that takes from 15 to 20 working days to be processed. Please e-mail us if you have any doubt.

---

> **13 AUSTRALIA**
> Visto Consular en Tránsito por periodo máximo 72 horas a partir del 9 de mayo 2020
>
> > Consular visa in transit for a maximum period of 72 hours from May 9, 2020

---

**Sources**:

- [ABOUT TRANSIT PASSENGERS - Chile en el Exterior - Sección Consular de Chile en Wellington](https://www.chile.gob.cl/wellington/about-transit-passengers)
- [TABLE OF FEES FOR VISAS AND TOURISM VISAS GRANTED ABROAD](https://serviciosconsulares.cl/tramites/site/artic/20190220/asocfile/20190220161313/cuadro_de_aranceles_y_vistos_de_turismo_2020.pdf) (in Spanish, PDF)

Comment: Is this a commonly understood interpretation with respect to visas? Because this is not how I understand up to 72 hours to mean.

Comment: It looks like Australians are one of the only nationalities where they will issue a up to 72 hour transit visa to: https://serviciosconsulares.cl/tramites/site/artic/20190220/asocfile/20190220161313/cuadro_de_aranceles_y_vistos_de_turismo_2020.pdf

Comment: @Alex Not many countries have passport stamps with hours on them. East Germany did, but their transit rule was to use the swiftest route. Most visas are for an amount of **days** or specific dates. The PDF text uses the term **maximum period**. If this is intended for a transit from Santiago towards the Argentina border, then you must really ask them per email how this is to be understood (as the other text sugests).